# how to solve $\int_{\frac{-\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{x^2}{\sin(x)} \ln\left(2^{\sin^3(x)}+ 5^{\cos^3(x)} \right)dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, contest-math

**Edit** the question had a typo that made it impossible to solve the question was $\int_{\frac{-\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{x^2}{\sin(x)} \ln\left(2^{\sin^3(x)}+ 5^{\sin^3(x)} \right)dx$ (to solve it just use king rule) and somehow it was written in the contest $\int_{\frac{-\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{x^2}{\sin(x)} \ln\left(2^{\sin^3(x)}+ 5^{\cos^3(x)} \right)dx$ and now I agree with @ClaudeLeibovici that probably there is no closed form for this question

---

I was this problem

> $$I:=\int_{\frac{-\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{x^2}{\sin(x)} \ln\left(2^{\sin^3(x)}+ 5^{\cos^3(x)} \right)dx$$

which was one of 10 integration problems in an integration contest and I tried to solve it

my attempt was:

since this terrifying looking thing has no antiderivative so there must some trick to solve it and the most obvious one is to substitute $x=-u$ and then return $u$ to $x$ again and add the $2$ integrals

$$2I=\int_{\frac{-\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{x^2}{\sin(x)} \ln\left(\frac{2^{\sin^3(x)}+ 5^{\cos^3(x)}}{1+ 5^{\cos^3(x)}2^{\sin^3(x)}} 
  \right)dx+\int_{\frac{-\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}x\sin^2(x) \ln(2) dx $$

the integral $\int_{\frac{-\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}x\sin^2(x) \ln(2) dx$ is easy to evaluate the problem is $\int_{\frac{-\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{x^2}{\sin(x)} \ln\left(\frac{2^{\sin^3(x)}+ 5^{\cos^3(x)}}{1+ 5^{\cos^3(x)}2^{\sin^3(x)}} 
  \right)dx$ there must be some simplification to make this integral doable but I was not able to find this simplification I even tried to make $\sin^3(x) =\frac{1}{4 }(3\sin(x)-\sin(3x))$ and  $\cos^3(x) =\frac{1}{4 }(3\cos(x)+\cos(3x))$ but it only made thing more messier

but I think this approach will lead to something
let $f(x):=\frac{x^2}{\sin(x)} \ln\left(2^{\sin^3(x)}+ 5^{\cos^3(x)} \right) \ \ g(x):=f(x)+ f(-x)$

when I graphed $g(x)$ (the blue function ) it looked very similar to the graph $x^2 \sin^2(x)$ (the purple function)

[image]

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe this integral has a closed form?

Comment: @Peder yes, this question was one of the problems in some integration contest in my friend's college

Comment: I suppose that, for a contest, my answer would have been : *close to $0$*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a bit skeptical about a possible closed form for

$$I=\int_{\frac{-\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{x^2}{\sin(x)} \log\left(2^{\sin^3(x)}+ 5^{\cos^3(x)} \right)\,dx$$

It can write (I suppose that this is a key)
$$I=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{x^2}{\sin(x)}\log \left(\frac{2^{+\sin ^3(x)}+5^{\cos ^3(x)}}{2^{-\sin
   ^3(x)}+5^{\cos ^3(x)}}\right)\,dx$$
$$\log \left(\frac{2^{\sin ^3(x)}+5^{\cos ^3(x)}}{2^{-\sin
   ^3(x)}+5^{\cos ^3(x)}}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\, x^{2n+3}$$
$$I=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\,\frac{x^{2n+5}}{\sin(x)}\,dx$$

We know that, if
$$J_m=\int \frac {x^m}{\sin(x)}\,dx$$ $$J_m=\frac {x^m}m+2\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}\frac{\left(2^{2 k-1}-1\right)\, B_{2 k}}{(2 k)! \,\,(2
   k+m)}\,\, x^{2 k+m}$$

So, we have all resuired elements to compute the definite integral as an infinite summation.

The problem is "just" to find the way to generate coefficients coefficients $a_n$. But, in paractice, this is not too difficult since the summation converges quite fast.

Computing exactly the partial sums and converting to decimals

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & \sum_{n=0}^p \\
 5  & \color{red}{0.022}24125 \\
 10 & \color{red}{0.022109}17 \\
 15 & \color{red}{0.0221098}3 \\
\cdots & \cdots \\
\infty & \color{blue}{0.02210985} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

For
$$I=0.022109848238413244272364409590123187230494\cdots$$ inverse symbolic calculators do not propose anything except (for the fun)
$$I\sim \frac{6^{1/3} \sqrt{10^{1/2}-2^{3/4}}}{100}$$

which is in an absolute error of $1.56\times 10^{-9}$ .